# Functions with a large set of singularities

Tags: real-analysis

Def: a function $f$ defined on $[0,1]$ is **total** at $x$ if the image of $f$ when restricted to any neighbourhood of $x$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that there are some functions which are total at every $x$ in $[0,1]$ but these are usually everywhere discontinuous.

I'm looking for continuous a.e . functions on $[0,1]$ which are total on a "large" set. Obviously, the set can't be either dense or have positive measure. But can it be uncountable?

Alternatively what if we change it so that we have continuity on merely a dense set. Can the "total" set have positive measure then?

Also some references to the study of functions with "large" sets of singularities on finite intervals would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer one of your questions:

Let $g:(-1,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $g(x) = \frac{\sin \frac 1x}{x}$ $(g(0) = 0)$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the Cantor Set. Let $\{I_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be the sequence of open intervals removed in the construction of $\mathcal{C}$.

We construct $f$ by scaling and shifting $g$ (via suitable transformations $x \mapsto ax+b$) to each $I_i$ and letting $f(x)=0$ for $x \in \mathcal{C}$.

This function is total for each $x \in \mathcal{C}$ and continuous except at $\mathcal{C}$ and *one* point in each $I_n$.

Hence, the function is total on an uncountable set and continuous almost everywhere.